# Multisites with different database share rules

Tags: rules, multi-sites

I create two sites with same code and different databases, but when I activate rules in the second site I can see the first site's rules.

I can disable the rules in second site and keep them active in the first, but rules with automatic name (ex. "Email on User Restriction") only appear one time.

Its a problem of my configuration? registry_rebuild.php does not fix.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Problem appear when a sigle site (default) is moved to a multisite (sites/XXX).
SOLUTION: erase rules in the other site don´t erase in the original site.